# Uploading PNG file to nginx server via HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA results in corrupted image

Tags: php, post, file-upload, nginx, png

I'm trying to debug this issue by posting raw PNG image data to the server with the help of [Postman](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/postman-rest-client/fdmmgilgnpjigdojojpjoooidkmcomcm). Here's a screenshot, which might help to understand the issue:

[image]

On the server I'm receiving the file as follows:

```
$png = $GLOBALS["HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA"];
```

Then I write the data to a new file:

```
$fh = fopen($myFile, 'w') or die("can't open file");
fwrite($fh, $png);
fclose($fh);
```

The file gets saved correctly, but it now has a different file size,
417KB instead of 279KB which is the size of the original file.

Now of course, I can't do any image operation as none of the functions (such as `getimagesize` which returns `bool(false)`) recognizes the file as a valid image.

I have debugged this process to a point where the issue must be somewhere in the file operations, but I don't understand why the file just doesn't result in the very same file type and size as the original, when the only thing I am doing is using the same raw data.

UPDATE:

I've now compared the encodings of the original file with the uploaded one,
and the former is in ISO-8859-1 and it displays correctly, the latter is in UTF-8 and has about 138kB more in file size.

Now I've achieved to convert the file on the server to ISO-8859-1.

```
fwrite($fh, iconv("UTF-8", "ISO-8859-1", $png));
```

The resulting file does now have the same output file size (279kB),
but it is still not recognized as a PNG image, some information seems to still get lost.

UPDATE (1):

I've been able to examine the issue further and found out, that the original file is exactly 4 bytes bigger than the generated file, thus the resulting PNG seems to be corrupted.

[image: Screenshot of the terminal showing the two different file sizes]

UPDATE (2):

I'm now able to save the file and open it as a valid PNG. The following code seems to be saving the image correctly:

```
$input          = fopen("php://input","r+");
$destination    = fopen($myFile, 'w+');

stream_copy_to_stream($input, $destination);

fclose($input);
fclose($destination);
```

However when trying to open the file with the `imagecreatefrompng` function I get a 500 error. I'm now trying to figure out if it's a memory issue in PHP.

Answer (score 1):

Problem might be the way you test your POST by copying the "binary" data into a text field.

If you paste the same data into a text editor you won't get a valid image file either when saving this with the png extension.

Try to build a simple form with file field to test your upload

Comment: I've opened the file in Smultron, copied the raw data, opened another document, pasted the data, changed the encoding to the same as of the original file (ISO-5589-1) and saved it. The resulting output is a perfectly functioning PNG image. The problem is not with my test but somewhere with encoding/writing the file I guess.

Answer (score 0):

I use nginx for uploads and haven't had a problem, but I use the standard PHP way of uploading files as per: http://www.php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.post-method.php

I would suggest trying that.

Comment: Thanks, but in my case I have no influence on how data is passed to the script, so I don't see any other way than reading the HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA parameter.

Comment: Isn't the raw post data everything, including field names etc - which is why it would be bloated? I've also used php://input with success on nginx for file uploads.

Comment: The resulting file includes exactly the same data as the data from the original file where I copy it from. This means it is correctly passed across the server and the problem probably lies somewhere else.

Answer (score 0):

Try using: < ?php $postdata = file_get_contents("php://input"); ?>
To get the raw data. I use it some times to get data sent from a ajax post on cake.

Comment: Thanks, I've replaced the line with what you proposed, however I'm still having problems, see update of my post.